# How to store images in Redis/What are some Redis use cases?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, redis, persistence

Im working on an assignment, i'm creating a simple React/Node web app that allows a user to upload an image and perform a variety of image processing on that image with the Sharp library. I'm required to use two persistent services and be able to justify the use of them, I'm using an S3 bucket to store the images long term, and I would like to use Redis as my other persistence service.

However I have read that Redis is not ideal image storage, so I'm exploring other options to justify using Redis. My app doesn't do a great deal besides uploading images to S3, so I don't really know what I can do here.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the redis for this purpose, but you can to store images in Redis. Redis keys and values are both binary-safe

> Redis Strings are binary safe, this means that a Redis string can
> contain any kind of data, for instance a JPEG image or a serialized
> Ruby object.
>
> A String value can be at max 512 Megabytes in length.

[See Data types](http://qnimate.com/storing-binary-data-in-redis/)

You can store the image in binary instead of base64

[See Storing Binary Data in Redis](http://qnimate.com/storing-binary-data-in-redis/)

in a normal scenario, I would use the redis at most to store a image_url, pointing to the location of the image on a server